# Explanation of a step in a preprinted work

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have been studying [this preprinted paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.01482.pdf) and the references therein. I believe that there are some typos; However, since I am not an expert yet, I would like to make sure I am correct.

I do not understand how the author made the restriction in the paragraph after equation (2.5)? in particular $ l \le 2j+2$.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Asking multiple questions in one post is not encouraged on MO. Also, doing so is not beneficial to the OP. Having only one question per post will likely attract more views, and people will likely be more willing to commit to answering just one question.

Comment: Why don't you write directly to the Authors of the paper? usually, they appreciate your interest and are eager to know about possible errors in their work

Comment: @IosifPinelis I edited the question.

Comment: Apparently you never read  Serre's "How to write mathematics badly". In particular his remark "On a theorem of Euler".

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer Sorry I did not understand!

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer I am watching the YouTube video, thanks.